# Unable to read or right data to/ from Firestore SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, firebase, swiftui

I've setup Firestore DB and wanted to test it. However I was unable neither read or wright data to it. Here is what console shows on connection status to Firebase.

Debug Console:

```
2020-11-19 17:58:49.802849+0300 Demo [813:165300] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60900000 started
2020-11-19 17:58:49.803819+0300 Demo [813:165300] 6.34.0 - [GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler][I-SWZ001014] App Delegate does not conform to UIApplicationDelegate protocol.
2020-11-19 17:58:49.804498+0300 Demo [813:165300] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev3ec8a1cb4)
2020-11-19 17:58:50.586054+0300 Demo [813:165306] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-11-19 17:58:51.138985+0300 Demo [813:165306] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2020-11-19 17:58:51.139362+0300 Demo [813:165306] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:FIREventScreenView parameters:] to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2020-11-19 17:58:51.850205+0300 Demo [813:165012] [AXRuntimeCommon] This class 'SwiftUI.AccessibilityNode' is not a known serializable element and returning it as an accessibility element may lead to crashes
```

Also Firebase it self shows that I had some reads in stats.
I stuck and don't understand what important part I didn't do in order to start implementing Firebase use. Will appreciate any help or suggestion.!

I used several methods to initiate Firebase in SwiftUI.

This one:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase


@main
struct DemoApp: App {
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onOpenURL(perform: { url in
                    
                    Auth.auth().canHandle(url)
                })
        }
    }
```

Also tried with DelegateAdaptor:

```
@main
struct DemoApp: App {

    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
        appDelegate
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    print("Application is starting up. ApplicationDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.")
    return true
  }
}
```

To test writing to:

```
func letE() {

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    db.collection("wine").addDocument(data: ["Cool" : 2017])

}
```

And to fetch an array

```
 private var db = Firestore.firestore()

    func fetchData() {
        db.collection("collection").document("document")
            .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
              guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
                print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                return
              }
                guard let data = document.data()!["array name"] else {
                print("Document data was empty.")
                return
              }
            print(data)
            }
```

And like this:

```
func getData(){

        db.collection("skills").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                }
            }
```

Hello, Peter! I was trying to come to solving this problem from different angels but still no luck.

Basically I am trying to perform wright operation

It goes like this

```
@main
struct DemoApp: App {

    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onOpenURL(perform: { url in
                    
                    Auth.auth().canHandle(url)
                })
        }
    }
}

func addData() {
        //
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
        //
            db.collection("wine").addDocument(data: ["Test":100])

        }
```

Then i press Build.

From my understanding that already should create collection "Wine" with autogenerated Document with contains field "Test" with value "100"

But once again nothing happens on the firebase side.

The Debug console

```
2021-01-26 16:22:21.907902+0300 Demo [27616:342494] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60900000 started
2021-01-26 16:22:21.908067+0300 Demo [27616:342494] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev3ec8a1cb4)
2021-01-26 16:22:21.934626+0300 Demo [27616:342498] 6.34.0 - [GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler][I-SWZ001014] App Delegate does not conform to UIApplicationDelegate protocol.
2021-01-26 16:22:21.979114+0300 Demo [27616:342490] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
2021-01-26 16:22:21.994921+0300 Demo [27616:342490] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2021-01-26 16:22:22.000217+0300 Demo [27616:342490] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2021-01-26 16:22:22.000724+0300 Demo [27616:342490] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:FIREventScreenView parameters:] to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2021-01-26 16:22:22.032550+0300 Demo [27616:342197] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000341ce60 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fb0e7d16480]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fb0e7d0a710'Skills']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000341ceb0 'CB_Trailing_Trailing' _UIModernBarButton:0x7fb0e7d0a710'Skills'.trailing <= _UIButtonBarButton:0x7fb0e7d10cb0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000341dc20 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' _UIModernBarButton:0x7fb0e7d16480.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x600002e54ee0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000341dc70 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fb0e7d10cb0]-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600002e54e00'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000347eda0 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' UILayoutGuide:0x600002e54e00'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x7fb0e7e0f7e0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000341e3f0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x7fb0e7e0f7e0.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000347e9e0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600002e54ee0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x7fb0e7e0f7e0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000341ce60 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fb0e7d16480]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fb0e7d0a710'Skills']   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

The changed Debug Console outcome presented is because I've setup authorised access and it does work. I can create user and then perform login with crated login and password. All users do show up on the Firebase console.

Comment: Check your Security Rules. They might prevent reading/writing your data.

Comment: Thanks for replay! I also thought that it might be something with it but prier to expiration date of testing period I've extended it till 28th of November.
Here is how it looks now:

`rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 11, 28);
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Seems like your Security Rules should grant full access to your Firestore database until the end of November (keep in mind to implement proper Security Rules to protect your data). It's a bit difficult to tell what's going wrong without more information, esp. since the individual code snippets don't seem to be related. Please provide a coherent code snippet that exposes the behaviour, as well as some console output so we can help.

Comment: Hi Peter I've added my step by step actions in order to perform wright operation (see code snippets above)